# Django Queryset Select reverse

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to get the father name value of the model, I hope you can help me.

```
class Datos_usuario_DB(models.Model):
    activo = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    comentarios = models.TextField()
    fecha = models.DateTimeField() 


class Datos_respuesta_DB(models.Model):
    foraneo_datos_empresa_DB = models.ForeignKey(Datos_usuario_DB)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    comentarios = models.TextField()
    fecha = models.DateTimeField()
```

What I'm trying to get is nombre in Datos_usuario_DB,
When I arrive up to this point I do not know what else do

```
a = Datos_respuesta_DB.objects.filter(foraneo_datos_empresa_DB=2)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
a = Datos_respuesta_DB.objects.filter(foraneo_datos_empresa_DB=2)
a.values('foraneo_datos_empresa_DB__nombre')
```